# How do I change a paragraph into an array in PHP including the spaces and punctation

Tags: php, arrays, paragraph, preg-split, text-segmentation

I have a string like this `Hello? My name is Ben! @ My age is 32.`

I want to change it into an array with all words, spaces and punctuation as separate entities in the array. For example if I did `var_dump($sentence)` the array should look like this:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "?"
  [2]=>
  string(1) " "
  [3]=>
  string(2) "My"  
  [4]=>
  string(1) " "
  [5]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [6]=>
  string(1) " "  
  [7]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [8]=>   
  string(1) " "  
  [9]=>
  string(3) "Ben"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "!" 
  [11]=>
  string(1) " " 
  [12]=>
  string(1) "@"
```

etc...

The only code I've found which comes close to this is:

```
$sentence = preg_split("/(?<=\w)\b\s*/", 'Hello? My name is Ben! @ My age is 32.');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($sentence);
echo '</pre>';
```

which  outputs:

```
array(10) {
[0]=>
string(5) "Hello"
[1]=>
string(4) ". My"
[2]=>
string(4) "name"
[3]=>
string(2) "is"
[4]=>
string(3) "Ben"
[5]=>
string(6) "! @ My"
[6]=>
string(3) "age"
[7]=>
string(2) "is"
[8]=>
string(2) "32"
[9]=>
string(1) "."
}
```

How do i change this so the spaces and punctuation are separated in the array?

Comment: Include the word boundary in the capture group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for lookahead: just make [**preg_split**](http://php.net/preg_split) capture delimiters as well (with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option):

```
$str = 'Hello? My name is Ben! @ My age is 32.';
$arr = preg_split('/(\W)/', $str, null, 
  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/82583). With this setup, each `\W` (non-word) symbol is captured separately (as a delimiter), but all `\w` symbols are gathered into sequences (as parts of the string separated by `\W`).